# jQuery password login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, events

I'm trying to create a very simple (No need for it to be 'safe') page with a login box.

When the user enters a password, I want the button to go to a certain URL. If the password is incorrect, it should display an alert.

This is my code so far;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.login').click(function() {
    if ($('input:password').val() == "hello") {
      alert('Right Password!');
     else 
      alert('Wrong Password!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="password" id="password" />
  <input type="button" class="login" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

**What I expect my code to do:**
Put a click function on `.login` to check *if*: password is equal to 'hello' *then* go to a URL (used an alert for testing purpose) or *else*: alert a message.

**Issues I'm having:**
No current response to the button at all. If enter is pressed after filling in the field, the page reloads. I want my user to be able to trigger the button with the enter key as well, is this possible?

I'm loading the script in before I end my body, and calling on the library in my head.

Comment: Just as a general thing, I would suggest using `<input type="submit" />` instead of `type="button"`, and attach the event to `$('form').on('submit',function(e) {...});` - with this, you can call `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `}else{`, and for the enter you can use `keyup()` and detect the key that is pressed using `event.keyCode` to trigger the click of the `.login` button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.login').click(function() {
    if ($('input:password').val() == "hello") {
      alert('Right Password!');
    } else {
      alert('Wrong Password!');
    }
  });
  $('input:password').keyup(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $('.login').click();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="password" id="password" />
  <input type="button" class="login" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

For the redirect to an `url` you can use `window.location.href = 'your url goes here';`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is you are missing `{` brace.Because of this your code doesn't work.Try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.login').click(function() {
    if ($('input:password').val() == "hello") {
      alert('Right Password!');
    } else {
      alert('Wrong Password!');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> If enter
>   is pressed after filling in the field, the page reloads.

The *page reloads* on clicking the enter key, as the `form` is *submitted* - you can *disable* that using this:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

(Note that in **snippet**, *due to restrictions* you can't check `form` submit)

To *listen* for the enter key as well, you can use this:

```
$('input:password').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    $('.login').click(); // trigger click
  }
});
```

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // this prevents page reload on pressing enter
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // click listener
  $('.login').click(function() {
    if ($('input:password').val() == "hello") {
      alert('Right Password!');
    } else {
      alert('Wrong Password!');
    }
  });

  // respond to enter key
  $('input:password').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $('.login').click(); // trigger click
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="password" id="password" />
  <input type="button" class="login" value="Continue" />
</form>
```